# Error executing script War

Tags: grails

When I creating grails 1.3.7 application war. I have an error seen.

```
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /home/remya/Documents/Grails-1.3.7/
Base Directory: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 22923ms.
Running script /home/remya/Documents/Grails-1.3.7/scripts/War.groovy
Environment set to production
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work
     [gspc] Compiling 334 GSP files for package [medical] to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/classes
     [gspc] Compiling 41 GSP files for package [springSecurityUi] to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/classes
     [gspc] Compiling 4 GSP files for package [mail] to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage
Building WAR file ...
     [copy] Copying 1052 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage
     [copy] Copied 93 empty directories to 4 empty directories under /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/ui-performance-1.2.2
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/ui-performance-1.2.2
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/rest-0.7
     [copy] Copying 32 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/rest-0.7
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.1.2
     [copy] Copying 57 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.1.2
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/mail-1.0
     [copy] Copying 32 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/mail-1.0
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/jquery-1.7.1
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/jquery-1.7.1
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15
     [copy] Copying 79 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/famfamfam-1.0
     [copy] Copying 1000 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/plugins/famfamfam-1.0
     [copy] Copying 348 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/grails-app
     [copy] Copied 62 empty directories to 4 empty directories under /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/grails-app
     [copy] Copying 400 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
     [copy] Copying 5023 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/spring
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
     [copy] Copied 2 empty directories to 1 empty directory under /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/templates/scaffolding
     [copy] Copying 6 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/templates/scaffolding
     [copy] Copying 90 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF
   [delete] Deleting: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/resources/web.xml
     [copy] Copying 4 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/lib
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/ui-performance-1.2.2
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/ui-performance-1.2.2
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/rest-0.7
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/rest-0.7
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.1.2
     [copy] Copying 43 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-ui-0.1.2
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/mail-1.0
     [copy] Copying 7 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/mail-1.0
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/hibernate-1.3.7
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/hibernate-1.3.7
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/jquery-1.7.1
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/jquery-1.7.1
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/famfamfam-1.0
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/famfamfam-1.0
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-acl-1.1
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-acl-1.1
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/aws-1.2.12.2
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/aws-1.2.12.2
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.2
     [copy] Copying 3 files to /home/remya/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE/purpleHealthV1/target/work/stage/WEB-INF/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.7.2
UiPerformance: versioning resources ...
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen the same error, which results from ResourceVersionHelper.groovy, line 67 in the ui-performance plugin (version 1.2.2). It seems that it is trying to find the version number from an SVN file which causes an error (possibly the wrong format?).

```
    File entries = new File(basedir, '.svn/entries')
    if (entries.exists()) {
        return entries.text.split('\n')[3].trim() //this throws the error
    }
```

Above this line in the code, it first looks for a closure in the config file to get the version number, so by providing this closure in Config.groovy, it no longer tries to find the version number from this mysterious file.

Below is what fixed the error - a closure in Config.groovy which returns version '1.2.2'

```
uiperformance {
    determineVersion = {
        "1.2.2"
    }
}
```